# Dotnet core segmentation fault on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, anglesharp

I have used AngleSharp to parse a website in a Dotnet core App It works fine in Windows but on Debian It crashed with this error :
Segmantion fault

the url that I had for parsing was https when I replaced it with an http url, It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem caused by conflicting between two version of libssl.
You can check version installed  :

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```

and By removing the version 1.0 my problem resolved :

```
apt-get remove ssl1.0.0.0
```