# Ubuntu - Segmentation Fault Error upon running dotnet new console

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu

When I try to run 'dotnet new console' in either the Ubuntu or VS Code Terminal, I get the following error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running it in the Ubuntu Terminal seems to give more information, looks like it's failing to do the 'dotnet restore' that automatically runs when you do 'dotnet new console'

```
Getting ready...
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /home/max/Programming/C Sharp/Hello World/Hello World.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running dotnet restore manually just gives the segfault error

Version of Ubuntu is 21.04, I have already installed everything as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2104-

Another thing to note is that I can build and run C Sharp applications fine in Monodevelop, and I can run non .NET languages such as Python fine in VS Code

Any ideas / assistance would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358732/dotnet-core-segmentation-fault-on-linux   (conflict two version of libssl)

Comment: Hi, only one version of libssl installed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

most likely, you installed dotnet-sdk by snap. You make unistall by snap and install by microsoft website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2110-

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this by uninstalling both .Net and VS Code via the instructions on Microsofts website, then installing again via the terminal commands / .deb file from Microsofts website

I had previously installed VS Code from the Ubuntu App Store, rather than via the .Deb from Microsoft